# How to create a composite index with Drift?

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor, drift

In SQLite, you can create a composite index and query along multiple fields with that index. Does Drift allow you to do this?

Comment: Maybe, I've just started using it but there is this class here, not sure how to implement it, though it says there that it's mainly used by generated code. https://pub.dev/documentation/drift/latest/drift/Index-class.html

Comment: Found it! Here it's a bug with the positioning so read this issue, they also say how to make it work: https://github.com/simolus3/drift/issues/686